# How to search SVN repository for a file when I'm not sure where I put it?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Co-worker is sure he checked in a file: foo_oustanding.dpr but isn't sure when/where (we have lots of "tools" and "utility" ancillary branches, lots of project branches, etc..
I need a way to search the entire repository for this file. I could check the whole source tree out to my HD, but that would take several hours.  Is there a faster way?  I tried the Repo Browser (Tortoise) and it didn't seem to have a search.  I also thought about dumping the log, from the beginning of time.  But that seemed silly.

I have, at my disposal:

- Tortoise SVN 1.6
- Subversion 1.5.6 running on Apache
  It runs on a Windows 2003 server.
- Remote Desktop access to the server, with admin rights.

Comment: appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391718/how-can-i-search-an-svn-repository-for-the-existance-of-files-in-any-revision

Comment: oops - sorry, it IS a duplicate! However, I'm glad I asked anyway, as the answers here are better, particularly @Ken's example of the svn log command.  Voted close.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Search in SVN repository for a file name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704901/search-in-svn-repository-for-a-file-name)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it was checked in fairly recently, you could do a verbose remote `svn log` from the top of the tree and see a history of all the commits across all the branches. You could then grep the output for the file and user name. (You would need the command line svn to do this.)

> svn log -v -l 500 http://myserver/svn_root

Comment: FWIW [Subversion 1.8](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#svn-log-search) now allows you to `--search` the log directly instead of having to grep the result of the `svn log` command.

Answer (score 15):

To see a list of all the files, send grep to text file in Command Prompt:

```
svn list -R myurl >> results.txt
```

Answer (score 10):

With **Subversion 1.8+ client**:

`svn log -v URL-OF-REPO-ROOT --search foo_oustanding.dpr`

Answer (score 7):

Good question! There doesn't seem to be an official "search" function in Tortoise, but it seems to be possible to [search the log in TortoiseSVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391718/how-can-i-search-an-svn-repository-for-the-existance-of-files-in-any-revision) for file names, which can be enough in many cases.

Answer (score 2):

See this question and answers:

[SVN Repository Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254214/svn-repository-search)

[svnquery](http://svnquery.tigris.org/) is probably what you need.

Answer (score 2):

I search like this:

```
svn list -R url_to_repo | grep Maintain.jar
```

It outputs this:

```
trunk/Project/pkg/Release/Maintain.jar
```

Comment: FYI, you can replace "grep" with "findstr" (in this example) on Windows.